# Fitting Flex Items inside certain height Div

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to fit dynamically added items into a flex div of a certain height. For example my container div is 100% width and 25vh height and I have 50 images loading inside of it within their child containers. I want these containers to resize accordingly and to fit inside that div, staying inside of it, 6-7 child divs per row. So far when I use flex-grow:15% value and they get moved to a new row, they don't resize at all and overlap outside, moving of the div. Is there any way to make it work?

Here is what I do:

```
<div class="brand-container">
   <div class="tier-top-1">

      <div class="tier-item">
         <img src="cat.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="tier-item">
         <img src="cat.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="tier-item">
         <img src="cat.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="tier-item">
         <img src="cat.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="tier-item">
         <img src="cat.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="tier-item">
         <img src="cat.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="tier-item">
         <img src="cat.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="tier-item">
         <img src="cat.jpg" />
      </div>

   </div>
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
.brand-container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
}

.tier-top-1 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 25vh;
    background: white;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.tier-item {
    margin: 1rem;
    justify-self: center;
    text-align: center;
    flex: 1 1 15%;
}

.tier-top-1 img {
    max-height: 20vh;
}
```

Comment: Great question. Can you explain which container you would like to see expand? Are you expecting the images to get really small and fit within the `25vh` div or are you expecting the `25vh` container to grow?

Comment: yes, I need the images to get smaller as there are more and more of them, adding around 6-7 per row and parent container to stay a fixed height and 100% width.

Comment: With the amount of margin plus the height of images coming into play, to have only 6 or 7 images per row, you need to be able to run a calculation using JavaScript to set the `max-height` of each image as `25vh` minus the space between rows, that difference divided by the number of rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the amount of margin plus the height of images coming into play, to have only 6 or 7 images per row, you need to be able to run a calculation using JavaScript to set the max-height of each image as 25vh minus the space between rows, that difference divided by the number of rows.

I adjusted the flex value to be `0 0 13vw` and adjusted the margin to just be `margin-top` for the images. You may have to calculate this number for various scenarios as well.

See the snippet below. Click on Full Page to see the solution. Otherwise, the `vh` units will be calculated from the height of your browser, not the height of the snippet window.

```js
const imgs = document.querySelectorAll(".tier-top-1 img");
const numImgs = imgs.length;
const rows = Math.ceil(numImgs / 7);
const maxHeight = (25 - rows - 1) / rows;
imgs.forEach(img=> img.style.maxHeight = maxHeight + "vh");
```

```css
.brand-container {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
}

.tier-top-1 {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    height: 25vh;
    background: white;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.tier-item {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin-top: .5vh;
    align-self: center;
    text-align: center;
    flex: 0 0 13vw;
}

.tier-top-1 img {
    max-height: 13vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="brand-container">
   <div class="tier-top-1">

      <div class="tier-item">
         <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x400/?text=Image" />
      </div>
      <div class="tier-item">
         <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x400/?text=Image" />
      </div>
      <div class="tier-item">
         <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x400/?text=Image" />
      </div>
      <div class="tier-item">
         <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x400/?text=Image" />
      </div>
      <div class="tier-item">
         <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x400/?text=Image" />
      </div>
      <div class="tier-item">
         <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x400/?text=Image" />
      </div>
      <div class="tier-item">
         <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x400/?text=Image" />
      </div>
      <div class="tier-item">
         <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x400/?text=Image" />
      </div>
      <div class="tier-item">
         <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x400/?text=Image" />
      </div>
      <div class="tier-item">
         <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x400/?text=Image" />
      </div>
      <div class="tier-item">
         <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x400/?text=Image" />
      </div>
      <div class="tier-item">
         <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x400/?text=Image" />
      </div>
      <div class="tier-item">
         <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x400/?text=Image" />
      </div>
      <div class="tier-item">
         <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x400/?text=Image" />
      </div>
      <div class="tier-item">
         <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x400/?text=Image" />
      </div>
      <div class="tier-item">
         <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x400/?text=Image" />
      </div>
      <div class="tier-item">
         <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x400/?text=Image" />
      </div>
      <div class="tier-item">
         <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x400/?text=Image" />
      </div>
      <div class="tier-item">
         <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x400/?text=Image" />
      </div>
      <div class="tier-item">
         <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x400/?text=Image" />
      </div>
      <div class="tier-item">
         <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x400/?text=Image" />
      </div>
      <div class="tier-item">
         <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x400/?text=Image" />
      </div>
      <div class="tier-item">
         <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x400/?text=Image" />
      </div>
      <div class="tier-item">
         <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x400/?text=Image" />
      </div>
      <div class="tier-item">
         <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x400/?text=Image" />
      </div>
      <div class="tier-item">
         <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x400/?text=Image" />
      </div>
      <div class="tier-item">
         <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x400/?text=Image" />
      </div>
      <div class="tier-item">
         <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x400/?text=Image" />
      </div>
      <div class="tier-item">
         <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x400/?text=Image" />
      </div>
      <div class="tier-item">
         <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x400/?text=Image" />
      </div>
      <div class="tier-item">
         <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x400/?text=Image" />
      </div>
      <div class="tier-item">
         <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x400/?text=Image" />
      </div>
      <div class="tier-item">
         <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x400/?text=Image" />
      </div>
      <div class="tier-item">
         <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x400/?text=Image" />
      </div>
      <div class="tier-item">
         <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x400/?text=Image" />
      </div>
      <div class="tier-item">
         <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x400/?text=Image" />
      </div>
      <div class="tier-item">
         <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x400/?text=Image" />
      </div>
      <div class="tier-item">
         <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x400/?text=Image" />
      </div>
      <div class="tier-item">
         <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x400/?text=Image" />
      </div>
      <div class="tier-item">
         <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x400/?text=Image" />
      </div>
      <div class="tier-item">
         <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x400/?text=Image" />
      </div>
      <div class="tier-item">
         <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x400/?text=Image" />
      </div>
      <div class="tier-item">
         <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x400/?text=Image" />
      </div>
      <div class="tier-item">
         <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x400/?text=Image" />
      </div>
      <div class="tier-item">
         <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x400/?text=Image" />
      </div>
      <div class="tier-item">
         <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x400/?text=Image" />
      </div>
      <div class="tier-item">
         <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x400/?text=Image" />
      </div>
      <div class="tier-item">
         <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x400/?text=Image" />
      </div>

   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm weak in JS and was looking for CSS solution. But your script did the job perfectly and it's also flexible. Thank you a lot!

Comment: No problem. We could craft a css only solution if we knew the exact number of picture containers, but since you mentioned that they are added dynamically, we need to leverage JS to help us out.

If you knew ahead of time the exact of rows, you can use the css `calc()` function within to set the `max-height` that way. `max-height: calc((25vh - 8vh) / 7)`